# In a nested tree, how can I select only the first element of certain class anywhere in the entire tree?

Tags: html, css

I have the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gdvx89s6/23/

As you can see, I have `record` nested inside another `record`:

```css
* {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.record {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.record[data-reaction="1"] .up {
  color: green;
}

.record[data-reaction="-1"] .down {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="record" data-reaction="1">
  <div class="something">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="buttons">
        <span class="up">UP</span>
        <span class="down">DOWN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator">-----------------</div>
  <div class="record" data-reaction="-1">
    <div class="something">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="buttons">
            <span class="up">UP</span>
            <span class="down">DOWN</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">-----------------</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `up` span to be green if the `data-reaction` is 1. I want the `down` span to be red if the `data-reaction` is -1.

Right now, since the second record is nested inside the first record, the `up` span in the second record is also being set to green. How can I avoid that?

[image]

I have tried adding a `:not(.record)` as such to "break the chain" but it doesn't work:

```
.record[data-reaction="1"] :not(.record) .up {
  color: green;
}


.record[data-reaction="-1"] :not(.record) .down {
  color: red;
}
```

NOTE that the `record` being nested inside another `record` can have multiple elements in between (in this easy example, it's directly nested at the first level but that's not always going to be the case).

I am trying to prevent having to specify the entire chain because there can be multiple elements in between.

Comment: Use `.record:nth-child(2)` to target the second `.record`.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen as far as I know, `nth-child` only works on siblings and doesn't work for descendants. So it won't work as the second `record` is not a sibling of first `record`. It's a descendant.

Comment: `:not(.record)` doesn't mean it doesn't contain `.record`. It means that there is some descendant that isn't `.record`.

Comment: I think you want `.record[data-reaction="-1"]:not(:has(.record))`. However, `:has()` is a new CSS feature, not supported in all browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you may be able to get away with specifying up and down in both conditions:

```
.record[data-reaction="1"] .up {
  color: green;
}
.record[data-reaction="1"] .down {
  color: black;
}


.record[data-reaction="-1"] .up {
  color: black;
}
.record[data-reaction="-1"] .down {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By adding a rule that uses the separator and `initial` it should do what you want:

```css
* {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.record {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.record[data-reaction="1"] .up {
  color: green;
}

.record[data-reaction="-1"] .down {
  color: red;
}
.separator + .record[data-reaction="-1"] .up, .separator + .record[data-reaction="1"] .down {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="record" data-reaction="-1">
  <div class="something">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="buttons">
        <span class="up">UP</span>
        <span class="down">DOWN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator">-----------------</div>
  <div class="record" data-reaction="1">
    <div class="something">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="buttons">
            <span class="up">UP</span>
            <span class="down">DOWN</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">-----------------</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if there are more nested records?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation We'd have to test it with an example